# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4' [sublime text 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, module, sublimetext3

Basically I am trying to run some simple code in sublime text 3 but when I try to run it it gives me the following error:

```
  File "/Users/ingodavila/Desktop/My Programming/scrape.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

I have tried installing it with pip3 and easy_install but it does not work. Whenever I try installing it it in terminal it keeps showing:

```
Requirement already satisfied: bs4 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from bs4) (4.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->bs4)
```

I tried running it in a jupyter notebook and it works but for sublime it keeps showing that 'nomodulefound' error. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the code inside a virtual environment?

If you are, try this method:

1. activate the env
2. install the module (inside the virtualenv)
3. run the code.

If the above doesn't work, try:

```
conda install bs4
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because your Sublime text interpreter is different than your global one. I would recommend you using virtual environment instead of just installing modules globally. Check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) one out on how to create `venv`. Once you set up your `virtualenv` and `active` it, you can just install packages and use them without any problem.